# How Can I Share the Port of a Socket from a Server Program?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, server, port

I have a simple TCP server which I wish to connect with a TCP client. This is all programmed in java. [See Here](https://gist.github.com/TrivialPants/ca96c0d52aeb2d1fec08).

I used the ServerSocket.accept() method to return a socket with a port allocated by java. (I set it to 0, thus randomly allocating the first available port).  However, when I wish to connect to my server via client, I can not find the port, because it is not saved anywhere or displayed on the server page. How can I know what port to connect to?

And for future reference when I wish to connect multiple clients, or when I am unable to see the server running in a terminal, how can I view the display the port to the public?

Thank you!

If you need any more detail, please ask. I am new to all of this, and I find it hard to put these concepts into words when I am only fairly comfortable with them.

Comment: What I've done is start it once where the port is assigned by the system, then hard code that port number into the code. If, on the other hand, you really want to keep your the port number variable, you can use either a File in a fixed place on the file system OR another ServerSocket set up on a fixed port to get the information on where the ServerSocket that's dynamically assigned a port is currently listening... Essentially, there has to be a fixed location/URL at some point for clients to go to

Comment: The port is allocated by TCP, not by Java.